# Redis Store + Express Session

Tags: node.js, session, redis, express-session

I notice that some of the project will use redis store and express session to save the user session

For example:

```
const session = require('express-session');
var redis = require("redis");
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var client  = redis.createClient();
var app = express();
app.use(session({
    secret: 'scret',
    store: new redisStore({
        host: '127.0.0.1', 
        port: 6379, 
        client: client,
        ttl : 7200
    }),
    saveUninitialized: true,
    // rolling: false,
    resave: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    } 
}));
```

What is the reason that we need to use these two Session Management function at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

`express-session` can be set up with different "stores" to save session data.

[MemoryStore](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/1010fadc2f071ddf2add94235d72224cf65159c6/session/memory.js#L33) comes with the package `express-session`.

The authors of `express-session` warn about this default store.

> Warning The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is
> purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak
> memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process,
> and is meant for debugging and developing.

Redis is one of the [compatible session stores](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores) and in this case is used "as a replacement" of a default store.